# How do I rewrite this as a function?

Tags: javascript, function

as part of a javascript course I've written a simple Caesar cypher script. I want to phrase it as a function but don't quite understand the syntax of functions.#
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkKAU.png)

```
var userinput = prompt("What's your message?");                 //get user input
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";                    //define alphabet
let alphabetupper = alphabet.toUpperCase();                     //define alphabet uppercase (else it gets messy to do the lookup!)
let shift=15;                                                   //define letter shift
//___________________________________________
let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++) {

    let letter = userinput[i];                                  //declare letter as userinput char at index
    if (letter.toLowerCase()==letter.toUpperCase()){            //if its not a letter...
        result +=letter;                                        //print it to result
    }

    else if ((letter===letter.toUpperCase()))  {                //else if it is an uppercase letter...
        let j=alphabetupper.indexOf(letter);                        //get index of letter in alphabet "j"
       if ((j+shift)<25){                                      //check shift pos is less than end of alphabet
      result+= ((alphabetupper[j+shift]));                     //print uppercase letter 15 places forward of result
       }
       else if ((j+shift)>25){                                 //if the new index is past z...
        result+=((alphabetupper[j+(shift-26)]));               //loop past z
       }
   
    }
    else if (/*(letter.toLowerCase()!==letter.toUpperCase())&&*/(letter==letter.toLowerCase()))  {   //if it is a lowercase letter...
        let j=alphabet.indexOf(letter);                        //get index of letter in alphabet "j"
       if ((j+shift)<25){                                      //check shift pos is less than end of alphabet
      result+= (alphabet[j+shift]);                            //print letter 15 places forward to result
       }
       else if ((j+shift)>25){                                 //if the new index is past z...
        result+=(alphabet[j+(shift-26)]);                      //loop past z
       }
   
    }
     
};
alert(("Your encoded message is ") + (result));                 //Output result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do now is run the code i called the function in the last line

```js
function ceasar (userinput){
  
var userinput = prompt("What's your message?");                 //get user input
let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";                    //define alphabet
let alphabetupper = alphabet.toUpperCase();                     //define alphabet uppercase (else it gets messy to do the lookup!)
let shift=15;                                                   //define letter shift
//___________________________________________
let result = "";
for (let i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++) {

    let letter = userinput[i];                                  //declare letter as userinput char at index
    if (letter.toLowerCase()==letter.toUpperCase()){            //if its not a letter...
        result +=letter;                                        //print it to result
    }

    else if ((letter===letter.toUpperCase()))  {                //else if it is an uppercase letter...
        let j=alphabetupper.indexOf(letter);                        //get index of letter in alphabet "j"
       if ((j+shift)<25){                                      //check shift pos is less than end of alphabet
      result+= ((alphabetupper[j+shift]));                     //print uppercase letter 15 places forward of result
       }
       else if ((j+shift)>25){                                 //if the new index is past z...
        result+=((alphabetupper[j+(shift-26)]));               //loop past z
       }
   
    }
    else if (/*(letter.toLowerCase()!==letter.toUpperCase())&&*/(letter==letter.toLowerCase()))  {   //if it is a lowercase letter...
        let j=alphabet.indexOf(letter);                        //get index of letter in alphabet "j"
       if ((j+shift)<25){                                      //check shift pos is less than end of alphabet
      result+= (alphabet[j+shift]);                            //print letter 15 places forward to result
       }
       else if ((j+shift)>25){                                 //if the new index is past z...
        result+=(alphabet[j+(shift-26)]);                      //loop past z
       }
   
    }
     
};
alert(("Your encoded message is ") + (result));                 //Output result
}
ceasar();
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a `function foo() {` before your code and an `}` after it, and you've created a function with the name `foo` and no arguments.

When you now call the function by invoking it

```js
foo();
```

you will execute the code between the curly braces `{...}`

Since ES6+ you can define the function as a const lambda (also code arrow function). like so:

```js
const foo = () => { /* all your code */ }
```

You just have to define the function before using it, the approach above allows it to use the function before it appears in the source code.

Comment: When I try, it breaks the code...